# How to generate index.html for each directory under /var/www/html

Tags: apache-httpd, htaccess

I have downloaded confluent software for upgrade under `/var/www/html` directory. I need to create an index.html for directory listing for each directory. I tried adding below to `.htaccess` file in the directory (I saw it somewhere, where the `index.html` existed with files in the directory), but it did not work:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Is there a utility or tool that will allow me to do that? Someone asked me to create it manually, but I don't really want to create it manually.

**UPDATE**

@Ipor Sircer / @Marcus Müller

I updated the `httpd.conf` file - now it is like below:

```bash
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

#
# Relax access to content within /var/www.
#
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +HTMLTable

    #Options None

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    #AllowOverride None
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is under `/var/www/html`:

```bash
pwd
/var/www/html

drwxr-xr-x 5 root root  86 Nov  7 18:10 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  33 Aug 12 15:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  46 Nov  6 13:35 clients
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  55 Nov  6 19:52 packages.confluent.io
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  17 Nov  6 15:57 rpm
```

But when I go to the server, I get the below:

[image: http://server]

Whereas if I go to `server/rpm`, I get this:

[image: http://server/rpm]

What else do I need to change, so I can see the directory under `/var/www/html` from the browser?

Comment: FancyIndexing...

Comment: *I need to create an index.html for directory listing for each directory.* That is a fallacy, your server can do that without a HTML file. Ipor above gives you the configuration setting to search for

Comment: Thank you.  Will search for it, how to use / where to add it.  I am not familiar with apache settings, and `did not` want to do it manually ( for sure )  as was asked.  Will post here once I find how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@Ipor Sircer` suggested, you can use `FancyIndexing` like you did in your updated configuration:

```bash
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    IndexOptions +FancyIndexing +HTMLTable
</Directory>
```

You can read more about what this option does [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/linux/apache/ch07_01.htm). However, this likely won't work if you don't have the Apache module enabled.

To enable the `mod_autoindex` module in your Apache configuration, run the command `sudo a2enmod autoindex` then restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`. Then your current configuration *should* display the directory contents as desired.

---

**Update**: My mistake, `a2enmod` is a [debianism](https://serverfault.com/a/558604/537331). This is how you can enable `mod_autoindex` on RHEL:

1. `sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`
2. In the configuration file, look for the `LoadModule` section, which contains the directives to load various Apache modules. Add the following line to enable `mod_autoindex`:

```bash
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
```

3. Save and exit with `CTRL+x` and confirm with `y`
4. Restart Apache with `sudo systemctl restart httpd`

Then `mod_autoindex` *should* be enabled on your system.

---

**Update 2:** Try following the instructions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974959/6456163), which involves removing the `welcome.conf` file and restarting the service again.

Comment: I am getting `sudo a2enmod autoindex`.  -   
`sudo: a2enmod: command not found`.  My environment is RHEL 7

Comment: My mistake, apparently `a2enmod` only works on Debian. I've updated my answer to a syntax that should perform the same function on RHEL.

Comment: I made the change and restarted httpd service.  I still don't see directory under `/var/www/html`.  What other change should I need to make?

Comment: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974959/6456163), it might work if you remove the `welcome.conf` file and restart again. Have you given that a try?

Comment: Thanks.  That worked.  Can you add it to the answer, and I will accept it?

Comment: @adbdkb added it!